# How can I zip and share my files in my Mendeley favorite

Tags: publications, reference-managers

My professor asked me to send the pdf files of my articles. However, I have about 80 articles in my Mendely favorites. The pdf files are on my PC but in different folders. I would like to know if there is any way to select them all, then zip all the physical files, or export or copy them to a folder, or any method so that I can have them together. The other option could be synching them with the Web; however, I don't know how then I can share the link of them to the prof. I prefer to have the pdf files in a folder.

Comment: do a command line copy that finds all pdfs and puts them into one folder, then zips them.

Comment: Meta discussion: [Technical support: rational vs emotion](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4403/14341)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible in new versions of Mendeley (Currently version 1.19.4). Then:

- Select all documents in favorites (Right click and click select all)
- Then right click and from context Menue (or click File) and select `Export PDF(s) with Annotations`
- It will ask you to save them in a new folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to sync with the web, there will be a way to set up a "group collection" or similar and share it with your professor (I'm afraid I don't remember the exact names of things, as I stopped using Mendeley many years ago). This will require your professor to also have a Mendeley account.